# Comma Delimited SQL string Need to separated

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have this string that i am getting from .net application
A,B,C,D,E,F,

I wanted to write a sql select statement like

```
set @string = 'A,B,C,D,E,F'

select * from tbl_test 
where tbl_test.code in (@string)
```

This wont work in t-SQL because it is using the `@string` as one string it is not separating the values.  Is there any ways i can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It think the easiest way to do it, will be, dynamic SQL generation:

```
// assuming select is a SqlCommand
string[] values = "A,B,C,D,E,F".Split(',');
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.Append("select * from tbl_test where tbl_test.code in (");
int i = 0;
foreach (string value in values) {
    string paramName = "@p" + i++;
    query.Append(paramName);
    select.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramName, value);
}
query.Append(")");
select.CommandText = query.ToString();

// and then execute the select Command
```

Answer (score 2):

3 options

1. Use a regular expression to replace the "," with "','" so that it becomes a proper ('A','B'...) list
2. Convert the list to XML and then parse the XML in your SELECT
3. [Write a SPLIT function](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/itai/archive/2009/02/01/t-sql-split-function.aspx) to convert comma delimited lists to tables

Answer (score 2):

Very frequently asked question! What you want is a table-valued function.

But don't reinvent the wheel by writing your own, I found dozens just by Googling `sql split`. Here's one from Microsoft:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SQLExamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=StringArrayInput

I used to use dynamic SQL for this, but that meant I had to dig up the code and copy it into each new app. Now I don't even have to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic IN clause means either:

1. Converting the comma separated list into a temporary table to join onto
2. Using dynamic SQL (EXEC or EXEC sp_executesql)

### Dynamic SQL example

---

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_test t
                 WHERE t.code IN (@string_param)

BEGIN

  EXEC sp_executesql @SQL N'@string_param VARCHAR(100)', @string

END
```

Mind that `sp_executesql` is 2005+, and preferred because it will cache the query plan.  Read [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) for more detail, but be aware of [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: @WingMan20-10: `@string` is a stored procedure parameter, matching the one you supplied in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a User Defined Function that takes the string as input and returns a table:

```
create function [dbo].[f_SplitString] (@str as varchar (1000))
returns @t table (value varchar (50))
etc...
```

Then adjust your Select statement:

```
select * from tbl_test 
where tbl_test.code in (select value from f_SplitString(@string))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that returns a delimited String as a set of rows

```
set @string = 'A,B,C,D,E,F'      

select * from tbl_test       
where tbl_test.code in (select r from ftDelimitedAsTable(',',@string )    


  --/*----------------------------------------------------------------
    Create     FUNCTION [dbo].[ftDelimitedAsTable](@dlm char, @string varchar(8000))
    RETURNS 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------------
    declare @dlm  char, @string varchar(1000)
    set @dlm=','; set @string='t1,t2,t3';
    -- tHIS FUNCION RETUNRS IN THE ASCENDING ORDER
    -- 19TH Apr 06
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    --declare
        @table_var TABLE 
        (id int identity(1,1),
            r varchar(1000) 
         )
    AS
    BEGIN
    -- a.p --
    --Modified  18th Nov. 04

        declare @n int,@i int
        set @n=dbo.fnCountChars(@dlm,@string)+1
        SET @I =1
        while @I <= @N
            begin

                --print '@i='+convert(varchar,@i)+ ' AND INSERTING'
                insert @table_var
                    select dbo.fsDelimitedString(@dlm,@string,@i)
                set @I= @I+1

            end
    --PRINT '*************** ALL DONE'
        if @n =1 insert @TABLE_VAR VALUES(@STRING)
    --select * from @table_var
        delete  from @table_var where r=''
        return
    END


USE [QuickPickDBStaging]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fsDelimitedString]    Script Date: 02/22/2010 12:31:37 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

Create function [dbo].[fsDelimitedString](
            @DelimiterStr varchar(100)
            ,@str varchar(4000)
            ,@pos int=1)
 returns varchar(4000)
as
/*
AP -- Dec 2003
Declare @DelimiterStr varchar(4000),@str varchar(4000) ,@pos int
set @delimiterStr = '-'
set @pos=10
set @str ='wd-1-22-333-4444-55555-666666-q-9'
*/
Begin
declare @rx varchar(4000)
set @rx=''; set @pos=@pos-1
IF DBO.fnCountChars(@DelimiterStr,@str) > 0 
    Begin
        if dbo.fnCountChars(@delimiterStr,@str) < @pos
        begin
            set @rx= null
            goto nulls
        end
        declare @i1 int,@tPos int,@ix int

        set @ix=1
        set @tPos=0
        while @tpos <> @pos
        Begin
            set @ix=charindex(@DelimiterStr,@str,@ix+1)
            if @ix > 0 set @tpos=@tpos+1
        end
        set @i1= charindex(@DelimiterStr,@str,@ix+1)
        if @i1=0 
                set @rx=substring(@str,@ix+1,len(@str)-@ix)
        else
            begin
                if @ix=1  
                    set @rx=substring(@str,@ix,@i1-@ix)
                else
                    set @rx= substring(@str,    @ix+1,@i1-@ix-1)        
            end
    --  'print 'ix='+convert(varchar,@ix)+' @i1='+convert(varchar,@i1)+' @rx='+@rx
        RETURN @RX
    end
nulls:  
    RETURN  @rx
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- If you are OK with it, just compose the **SQL statement dynamically** before making call to SQL. There is a limitation on the number of values in the `IN` statement
- Use **Table-valued UDF** that splits the string and returns the table. Then your query would either use `IN` or better just `JOIN` statement (among other implementations I favor [SQL User Defined Function to Parse a Delimited String](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQL_UDF_to_Parse_a_String.aspx)).

The you code would be:

```
select     tbl_test.*
from       tbl_test 
inner join fn_ParseText2Table(@string) x
       on  tbl_test.code = x.txt_value
```

- Since you use SQL Server 2005, you can write **CLR Table-valued UDF** that would do the same job as previous UDF does, which would be much smaller and faster since string operations in CLR are way better handled that in `SQL`.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep it really simple with built-in sql functions:

```
set @string = 'A,B,C,D,E,F'

select * from tbl_test 
where CHARINDEX(ISNULL(tbl_test.code, 'X'), @string) > 0
```

PATINDEX can be used in case you need more than one character.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing simple.  You can write a function that will take in that list and split it apart into a table you can query against in the IN() statement.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I thought I would post an answer to it anyway. I never liked passing in comma delimited string values, so I have used XML in the past and used a join statement on the xml like so:

```
declare @xml as xml
set @xml = '<v id="key1" /><v id="key2" /><v id="key3" />'
select
    t.*
from
    mytable t join @xml.nodes('/*') x(n)
    on n.value('@id','varchar(50)') = t.mykey
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the easiest way is as below,

- Option1:

  ```
  set @string = '''A','B','C','D','E','F'''

  Exec ('select * from tbl_test 
  where tbl_test.code in ('+@string+')')
  ```
- Option2:

  ```
  set @string = '''A','B','C','D','E','F'''

  DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

  SET @SQL='select * from tbl_test 
  where tbl_test.code in ('+@string+')'

  exec sp_executesql @SQL;
  ```