# Counting delimiter in String and splitting the other character between the delimiter in SQL Server using loop

Tags: sql-server

I have a procedure in SQL Server 2008 ,which I have a query as below :

```
 SELECT @symbol += N'' + acc_no FROM dbo.sav_acc_mcg where scheme_id = @scheme_id and  status in (1,2) order by acc_no
```

which extracts all the "acc_no" from table and save it into @symbol. But the length of "acc_no" individually can vary. So I am thinking that I can use delimiter to separate each "acc_no" and then use a loop to extract every single "acc_no" by checking the the delimiter. Also I need to count the number of "acc_no".
If the length of each "acc_no" would have been same and without delimiter, e.g.10. I could have use the following code to count the number of "acc_no":

```
@count = len(@symbol)/10
```

And to extract each "acc_no" I could have use the following code :

```
@loop =  0
```

running the code below in a while loop until @loop<@count:

```
@acc_no = SUBSTRING(@symbol, (@loop*10)+1 , 10)
```

...................,etc

But due to the varying length of "acc_no" the above code will not work.

How to get the work done.
My requirement is like :
if

```
@symbol = PS-000001,GS-000002,CFS-000008,NS001-000016,CFS-000017,LS2-000019,......etc
```

I need to count the number of "acc_no" and then extract each "acc_no" for my other jobs.

Help is most welcomed.

Comment: You could use one of the many SplitString functions (adapted), returning a table e.g. [F_SplitAsIntTable](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15038078/1699210) or [f_SplitString](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2312627/1699210)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the job.

```
while @index1 < LEN(@symbol)
begin
set @index2 = CHARINDEX(',',@symbol,@index1)
set @op = substring(@symbol,@index1,@index2-@index1)
print @op
set @index1 = @index2+1
end
```