# Most effective way to check sub-string exists in comma-separated string in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, query-performance, sqlperformance

I have a comma-separated list column available which has values like

```
Product1, Product2, Product3
```

I need to search whether the given product name exists in this column.

I used this SQL and it is working fine.

```
Select * 
from ProductsList 
where productname like '%Product1%'
```

This query is working very slowly. Is there a more efficient way I can search for a product name in the comma-separated list to improve the performance of the query?

Please note I have to search comma separated list before performing any other select statements.

Comment: Normalize your table.

Comment: Without re-designing things, that's about as good as you're going to get, until people start telling you to do crazy things like full-text index the values. BTW, `like '%Product1%'` will also match on Product10 and Product101.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comma Delimited SQL string Need to separated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312581/comma-delimited-sql-string-need-to-separated)

Answer (score 0):

Felix is right and the 'right answer' is to normalize your table. Although, maybe you have 500k lines of code that expect this column to exist as it is. So your next best (non-destructive) answer is:

1. Create a table to hold normalize data:

   ```
   CREATE TABLE ProductsList2 (ProductId INT, ProductName VARCHAR)
   ```
2. Create a TRIGGER that on UPDATE/INSERT/DELETE maintains ProductList2 by splitting the string 'Product1,Product2,Product3' into three records.
3. Index your new table.
4. Query against your new table:

   ```
   SELECT * 
   FROM ProductsList 
   WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT x.ProductId 
                       FROM ProductsList2 x 
                       WHERE x.ProductName = 'Product1')
   ```

Answer (score 0):

[image]user defined functions for comma separation of the string

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[BreakStringIntoRows] (@CommadelimitedString   varchar(max))
RETURNS   @Result TABLE (Column1   VARCHAR(max))
AS
BEGIN
        DECLARE @IntLocation INT
        WHILE (CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0) > 0)
        BEGIN
              SET @IntLocation =   CHARINDEX(',',    @CommadelimitedString, 0)      
              INSERT INTO   @Result (Column1)
              --LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are   removed
              SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@CommadelimitedString,   0, @IntLocation)))   
              SET @CommadelimitedString = STUFF(@CommadelimitedString,   1, @IntLocation,   '') 
        END
        INSERT INTO   @Result (Column1)
        SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(@CommadelimitedString))--LTRIM and RTRIM to ensure blank spaces are removed
        RETURN 
END


Declare @productname Nvarchar(max)
 set @productname='Product1,Product2,Product3'
select * from product where [productname] in(select * from [dbo].[![enter image description here][1]][1][BreakStringIntoRows](@productname))
```